# Flutter - How to preserve widgets with data and states, when navigating using the NavigationBar class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the [NavigationBar class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html) for the navigation through my app, but I have a problem, which is that I can't preserve the information on the screen when I'm navigating, so everything loads up again at the start of the screen. How should I do to preserve the screen even if I am in another screen so everything doesnt load up again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bloc for your state management.

Answer (score 0):

Use [states](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro). There are a lot of [options](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) available like for example [stateful widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#setstate).